# django python shell data access error

Tags: python, django

I have a django model like the following:

```
from django.db import models
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey

class deg_course_cat(models.Model):
    degree_code = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    specialization = models.CharField(max_length=48)
    category_level1 = models.CharField(max_length=48)
    category_level2 = models.CharField(max_length=96)
    category_level3 = models.CharField(max_length=48)
    min_credit = models.IntegerField()
    max_credit = models.IntegerField()
    primarystuff = models.CharField(max_length=24)

class deg_course_cat_mptt(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=False)
    min_credit = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    max_credit = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['name']

# Create your models here.
```

My deg_course_cat table has some data already filled.

I am getting an error when i am trying to access a column in the data through the python shell. I tried something like this:

```
Python 2.7.4 (default, Sep 26 2013, 03:20:56) 
[GCC 4.7.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from studentapp.models import deg_course_cat
>>> from studentapp.models import deg_course_cat_mptt
>>> degree_code.items()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'degree_code' is not defined
```

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: Off topic, I'd suggest to use ClassName instead of class_name for your classes, see PEP8 http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access a model field like that. First of all, `degree_code` is not imported. Also, you cannot import it, you can access it through the model: `deg_course_cat.degree_code`, but I'm not sure what do you want to do with it.

If you want to get all the degree_code values out there, use [values_list()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values_list) with `flat=True`:

```
>>> deg_course_cat.objects.values_list('degree_code', flat=True)
```

This will return you a list of all `degree_code` values out there in the database.

Comment: I am trying to create an mppt structure using the data in the model.

Comment: Hi one more question! how do i get distinct values from the same column?

Comment: @AbhishekReddy sure, just make a set from it: `set(deg_course_cat.objects.values_list('degree_code', flat=True))`.

Comment: Hi, can you tell me how to use a filter in this command? I am trying something like set(deg_course_cat.objects.filter(degree_code='AA.ARTS').values_list('degree_code', flat=True))

Comment: @AbhishekReddy sure, just do it, for example: `set(deg_course_cat.objects.filter(min_credit=10).values_list('degree_code', flat=True))`